# problems with sudoers

Tags: visudo

if I run `sudo visudo` I get this page:
[image]

How can I fix?

Comment: Look like buffer underflow..what version of `nano`?

Comment: hi, the version should be 2.5.3-2 (seen with synaptic)

Answer (score 1):

I solved removing the file with the command:

```
sudo rm /etc/.sudoers.tmp.swp
```

now, `sudo visudo` works fine.